# Typescript Definition File For Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am very new to Typescript and I have an issue with the Mangific Popup lightsout plugin and type script is not playing nice with it.

So I made a new folder in my 'typings' folder and added it to the index.d.ts in the typings root folder. I think its using it right but I just don't know how to make file.

This is what I have done,

```
interface JQuery {
   magnificPopup(callback?: () => void): JQuery;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
  address: JQueryMagnificPopupStatic;
}

interface JQueryMagnificPopupStatic {
  (): JQuery;
  parameter(name: string): string;
  parameter(name: string, value: string, append?: boolean): JQuery;
}
```

Now this code did come from the another post on SO. But I am not sure what to do?

I have come across, dt-gen but that seems to only work on node modules? How do I use it if there is no node module, only a .js file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have (or it seems to be) work definition file for this plugin.

```
//Magnific Popup Definition File

interface JQuery {
  magnificPopup(callback?: () => void): JQuery;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
  magnificPopup: JQueryMagnificPopupStatic;
}

interface JQueryMagnificPopupStatic {
  open: any;
  (): JQuery;
  parameter(name: string): string;
  parameter(name: string, value: string, append?: boolean): JQuery;
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong in any way for this type of file. For the record, this is how I opened my div,

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: '#DivIDHere',
        type: 'inline'
      }
});
```

That is why I added a 'open' with the last interface, but I am not sure thats the best way to do it?

Many Thanks.